# How to check if endpoint was used in a munit test

Tags: java, xml, unit-testing, testing, mule

I am trying to write a mule munit test (in java) and I would like to check whether the message passed (or in this case exited) through a specific outbound-endpoint since there is routing in the flow and the message can pass through different ones depending on conditions?

My setup is to actually use 2 different flow files, one with the flow logic which uses generic endpoints such as

```
<outbound-endpoint ref="out.endpoint" />
```

And then another flow file with the actual endpoint definition such as

```
<vm:endpoint name="out.endpoint" path="out.path" />
```

The following java code works

```
verifyCallOfMessageProcessor("outbound-endpoint").times(1);
```

However I'd like to be able to specify the specific name of the endpoint. I have tried the following but none worked

```
verifyCallOfMessageProcessor("outbound-endpoint").withAttributes(attribute("name").withValue("out.endpoint")).times(1);
verifyCallOfMessageProcessor("outbound-endpoint").withAttributes(attribute("ref").withValue("out.endpoint")).times(1);
verifyCallOfMessageProcessor("endpoint").withAttributes(attribute("name").withValue("out.endpoint")).times(1);
verifyCallOfMessageProcessor("endpoint").withAttributes(attribute("ref").withValue("out.endpoint")).times(1);
```

All these 4 (Which are the ones that would make any sense to me) fail. Does anybody know how to accomplish this (Preferably through java otherwise using xml)?

Answer (score 1):

This should be the way:

```
verifyCallOfMessageProcessor("outbound-endpoint").ofNamespace("vm").withAttributes(attribute("name").ofNamespace("doc").withValue("out.endpoint")).times(1);
```

Check that the attribute name has the namespace "doc.